# Double Pendulum Cuspiness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

Does the curve traced out by the tip of a [double pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) have cusps?

[image]

Comment: I don't know, I would need the expression of the curve to tell. But speaking qualitatively from the animation, and complete guesswork, it looks like it is possible for the pendulum to be left shortly in some extreme position, only to be jerked back in a non-smooth manner.

Comment: The path is smooth in $\mathbb R^4$, simply because of the right-hand sides of the differential equations. But in general it is not smooth in the plane (or would you in fact consider smooth the trajectory of a simple pendulum inside the heteroclinics?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the curve may have cusps: If you release the pendulum in a state of rest, the resulting motion can be mirrored in time to obtain a trajectory on which the pendulum retraces its path, which thus "ends" at the point at which the pendulum was released. Here the time derivative is zero and changes sign, thus satisfying [the definition of a cusp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_%28singularity%29).

Comment: I'll edit the question to be more precise.

Comment: @MarkB: OK, I've edited the answer in response.

Comment: I guess this supposes (for a given set of IC) the existence of a solution for all time. I assume this is true, but why?

Comment: @MarkB: I'm sure there's a mathematical theorem to prove this, but the most direct proof is physical: If you release a double pendulum, it does something :-)

Comment: I guess my main hangup is that in order for the derivative to change sign, it needs to be defined for $t<0$, and I'm not sure how that's true from a physical point of view.

Comment: @MarkB: I'm not sure I understand your problem. For concreteness, let's talk about a simple pendulum, where we know the solution explicitly. Do you doubt that the approach works for a simple pendulum? More formally speaking, use initial conditions $\vec x(0)=0$ and $\dot{\vec x}(0)=0$, solve for the motion $\vec x(t)$ in the future, and set $\vec x(-t)=\vec x(t)$ in the past. The entire trajectory $\vec x(t)$ then satisfies the equations of motion, and the velocity changes sign at $0$.

Comment: @MarkB: Perhaps your doubts are related to something like [Norton's slippery slope](http://www.socsci.uci.edu/~dmalamen/bio/papers/NortonDome.pdf)? I don't think this issue arises for the double pendulum, at least not if you release it in general position.